# TrueCrypt Volume Container Missing in Strange Circumstances

Tags: truecrypt

i have a truecrypt container for over 2 years now, i work on it everyday, the underlying file system is NTFS, and i am running truecrypt 7.0a/windows 7 x32, no hidden volume, and the truecrypt volume format is FAT32 i was working on it until late last night, and i don't remember if i unmount or not before turning off the computer, but this morning, 2 hours after running the computer, i tried to browse for the truecrypt container, and it was gone, the file was not there !!!!!

is it possible that it somehow was corrupted or deleted by truecrypt or operating system? or have i been hacked???

Comment: You have not been hacked.  The file likely was deleted by chkdisk because at the core of the problem your starting to experience a HDD failure.

Comment: but i did not run chkdsk or saw it running at startup!

Answer (score 0):

Truecrypt cannot suddenly delete the file. It could of been accidentally deleted or it has been corrupted. A disk scan for bad sectors/ data corruption will determine if the problem was of such nature.

Another option would be for windows to delete it at a junk cleanup, if it was named similar to temporary files (name.bak, name.old, name.tmp).

Comment: i ran chkdsk, it didn't find any bad sectors (0 bytes in bad sectors)